# confusion in Header search path for adding static library in xcode 4.x?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4.5

I am getting confused in adding core plot static library in xcode 4.5. it is different from xcode 3.x versions. I tried many things, it gave header file not found and linker errors.

I have followed the steps as follows. In which situation we have to use recursive in Header search path. If any has done wrongly, please help?

> 1)Adding coreplot  library and its headers in Xcode project.(ticked
>   for copy locally)
>
> 2)converted compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 in project build settings.(not in
>   target build setting)
>
> 3)Compiler for thumb will be **"NO"**
>
> 4)Added Header Search Path in project build settings as ,with
>   recursive
>             **"$(SRCROOT)/Libs/CorePlot/CorePlotHeaders"**
>
> 5)Added Header Search Path in target build settings as 
>              $(inherited)
>
> 6)Library search path will be  as empty in both target and project
>   build settings.
>
> 7)-ObjC was added in Other linker flag in target build
>   settings.Removed -all_load from it.
>
> 8)Always search path will be YES in both target and project build
>   settings.
>
> 9)Build archive architecture only will be **YES**.

Comment: Please post the exact compiler/linker errors you are getting.

Comment: hi, please tell correct steps to integrate and dos and donts to avoid .h file not found , librARY linker errors?

Comment: Official documentation for adding Core-plot in your project. [http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications).

Answer (score 3):

I had same issues a couple a days ago when trying to add `CorePlot` this way but I found out that there is a far easier process :

> 1. Copy the CorePlotHeaders directory to your Xcode project
> 2. Copy the Core Plot library to your Xcode project.
> 3. Open your apps Target Build Settings, and for Other Linker Flags include this:
>
> -ObjC (-all_load used to be required as a linker flag, but this is no longer needed in Xcode 4.2)
>
> 1. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.
> 2. Change your C/C++ Compiler in the project build settings to LLVM GCC 4.2 or LLVM 1.6.

In my case, i did not need to change my `C/C++ Compiler` to make `CorePlot` working